# Trying to implement Linkedin Oauth2.0 full authentication flow

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, vercel

I'm trying to implement the Linkedin OAuth2.0 sign in and authentication flow and I can't seem to find any resources that show step by step exactly what needs to happen.

My project is built in next.js and hosted using Zeit's now serverless deployment. So my project is essentially a bunch of lambdas both for the front end and back end.

*So far I have the following flow working correctly:*

1) user navigates to /login page and clicks on Sign in with Linkedin button

2) The button routes the client to the Linkedin Authentication URL where they see will see the Linkedin sign in prompt

3) User signs in and Linkedin redirects to my server callback url lambda

4) server callback lambda retrieves authorization code from the query string

5) server sends a POST to Linkedin's accessToken endpoint to retrieve the access_token

6) server receives the response and extracts the access_token.

Right now it then does a 301 redirect to redirect the user to another page.

Would should I be doing with the access_token? I understand that I need the token to access Linkedin's APIs to retrieve the user profile and any other API services. But my question is how should I store the access_token. I tried setting it in the response header as a cookie but it never shows in the session cookies. Should I be using JWT Cookies?

Here is the code for my auth callback lambda which sits at `/auth/linkedin/callback`

```
// api/login.js

const { json, send, createError, run } = require('micro');
const fetch = require('isomorphic-unfetch');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const nodeCookie = require('node-cookie');
const url = require('url');

const callback = async (req, res) => {

  let { query } = url.parse(req.url)
  let { code, state } = querystring.parse(query)

  // const redirectUri = req.redirectUri;
  let tokenUrl = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` + '?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: 'https://memory-app.sfkiwi.now.sh/auth/linkedin/callback',
      client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
      client_secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    });

  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      tokenUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      });

    if (response.ok) {

      let { access_token, expires_in } = await response.json();

      nodeCookie.create(res, 'liauth', String(access_token));

      res.setHeader('Location', '/profile');
      send(res, 301);

    } else {
      send(res, 500, response.status);
    }

  } catch(err) {
    send(res, 500, 'Failed to retrieve access token from Auth server');
  }
};

module.exports = (req, res) => run(req, res, callback);
```

Front end code for login page

```
async handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let qs = querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
      redirect_uri: this.props.apiUrl + '/auth/linkedin/callback',
      state: 'DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424',
      scope: 'r_liteprofile r_emailaddress w_member_social'
    });

    let url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization' + '?' + qs

    Router.push(url);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <div className="login">
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Login with Linkedin</button>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would should I be doing with the access_token?

The access token must be saved in your database or server and link it to that user, so any future access to this user's linkedin data or profile will be using this access token

> But my question is how should I store the access_token

I believe you already have somesort of a database, and in it you store information about your users, so this token should be saved with the user information